# Append div in order according to related div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a complex situation where I need to place a div with a numerical ID in the correct spot, based on related divs. I have been able to match a certain list of criteria, but I am missing the most complex case - where the ID of the div is not 1 less than or 1 greater than any other div.

All div IDs are unique and numerical.
All divs are found within Objects that are stored in an array.

Example: Already created Div IDs :

```
0
1
3
4
8
```

Div ID to place in order:
`2`

Solution

1. Find a `div` Id that is one less than `2` and place it after
2. Find a `div` Id that is one more than `2` and place it before

Now in that case, we have success. We will see that `1` is `1` less than `2` and place it after `1`. Or if `1` did not exist, we could place it before `3`. But in the case that our new div ID is `6`, we have no logic to place it.

You can take a look at this fiddle to see where my logic falls through.
http://jsfiddle.net/5egxoy78/1/

Comment: Just place it before the first div that has an id greater than the one you are placing.

Comment: Uh yup.. that was easy.

Comment: Provided that the divs are always going to be ordered properly. You just need to append before the first div which has a higher number / last div that has a lower number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you know that the IDs of each div are unique (i.e you won't try to insert a div with an ID which already is present), then you can loop through your divs and insert the new one *before the first div that has an ID which is larger than the one of the div you are inserting*.

Otherwise it's pretty much the same thing except you need to account for the condition where the ID of the div you are inserting is equal to the current div you are iterating through. Then you could just replace the contents.

**Edge Cases**

1. There are no divs. If `length == 0`, then append to parent.
2. There are no divs which have an id that is greater than or equal to the one you are trying to insert, then append to parent.

Comment: This would miss some cases, like no divs, the first div, the last div

Answer (score 1):

This solution is more or less doing the same thing as suggested by JOCO611. That is looping through all divs and adding the new div based on the ids traversed...

Of course if you are going to have thousands of divs - then I don't think this is a good solution!

```
var container = $('.container');

function Foo(id) {
    this.wrapper = $('<div id = "' + id + '" class = "wrapper">I am Foo # ' + id + '</div>');
    this.id = id;
    return this;
}

var foos = [];
foos[1] = new Foo(1);
container.append(foos[1].wrapper);
foos[2] = new Foo(2);
container.append(foos[2].wrapper);
foos[6] = new Foo(6);
container.append(foos[6].wrapper);



// Properly place foo with id of x 
var newFooId = 4;
foos[newFooId] = new Foo(newFooId);
var bFound = false;
var currFoo = null;
var f = $('div.container div.wrapper');
for (var i = 0; i < $('div.container div.wrapper').length; i++) {

    if ($(f[i]).prop('id') < newFooId) {
        currFoo = f[i];
    } else {
        if (currFoo === null) {
            container.prepend(foos[newFooId].wrapper);
        } else {
            $(foos[newFooId].wrapper).insertAfter($(currFoo));
        }
        bFound = true;
        return false; //break;
    }
}

if (!bFound) {
    container.append(foos[newFooId].wrapper);
}
```

See the [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/5egxoy78/2/)